# css nth-child() check board pattern

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

Imagine having a grid with four columns and n rows. Every second element should have a different color than the other. Kind of [the basic pattern](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-chess-board) but only with four columns.

I need this with one single parent which has `display: flex` on it. I tried to adapt the linked example but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: `Imagine having a grid with four columns and n rows` --> what if we don't have a good imagination :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, as the pattern is repeated over 2 rows of 4, you just need to apply styles to `8n + i` for the chequered pattern:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;        /* width of four squares */
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.square:nth-child(8n+1),
.square:nth-child(8n+3),
.square:nth-child(8n+6),
.square:nth-child(8n+8) {
    background:black;
}
.square:nth-child(8n+2),
.square:nth-child(8n+4),
.square:nth-child(8n+5),
.square:nth-child(8n+7) {
    background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="square"></div>
</div>
```